# Image is pixelated in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar

I would like to add an image to the middle of the `UINavigationBar`. I could do it easily, but the image that I set is always pixelated no matter what resolution options i use.

I tried these two solutions, but it's still pixeled.

```
//1.
UIImage *logoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];   
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:logoImage];

//2.
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
[myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
myImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
self.navigationItem.titleView = myImage;
```

I've tried to play with the image sizes, but the result was always abnormal. Is it any other solution that I could try? Or is there any recommended resolution for the png? I tried 100 x 100 px, 44 x 44 px and 30 x 30 px.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot?

Comment: @Mike I've changed the filename to logo@2x.png and works correctly.

Comment: I have the same problem, do you solve it?

Comment: @kova check my previous comment, I've just changed the filename.